# add InputMethodService subclass to manifest

Tags: android

If I create an InputMethodService, is it used by my app by default? Or do I need to go to settings to point to it? I created a subclass of InputMethodService called MultiInputMethodService so that I could have softkeyboard displayed even with a hardkeyboard attached. Is there anything I'm missing besides subclassing InputMethodService and adding the service to the manifest as follows?

MultiInputMethodService:

```
package com.mydomain;

import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.util.Log;

public class MultiInputMethodService extends InputMethodService {

        @Override
        public boolean onEvaluateInputViewShown () {
            Log.i("onEvaluateInputViewShow","onEvaluateInputViewShown");
             return true;
        }   
}
```

manifest file(added meta-data tag inside service and makes no difference so removed):

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <service android:name="MultiInputMethodService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
 ....
```

Comment: Try `android:name=".MultiInputMethodService"` (notice the preceding `.`)

Comment: What are your symptoms? It is difficult to help you when we do not know what the problem is.

Comment: when i disconnect the hard keyboard from usb the softkeyboard pops up as expected.  when i plug in the hard keyboard, the soft keyboard no longer appears.  Is there a way i can debug this to see if my subclass is getting called? btw, i used your online books for android and the tutorials were a great walk through.  thx

Comment: @squonk.  i tried .MultiInputMethodService but also the hard keyboard doesn't show.  It seems like it can find it without the "." because when i set it in the manifest gui, i see it links to it.  Any other ideas?